# How to use Azure AD Identity & Social Identities along with LDAP for authenticating Web API?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have a single-page application that communicates with a Web API. The Web API provides JWT to single-page applications validating user credentials using the local active directory. Now we are going to cover the Azure Active Directory & Social identities as well.

I've done some initial research work where we need to register applications in Azure and then have to pick up the Tenant Id, Client Id, etc. to use for a validation token but I still looking for the best of doing.

I've heard about the MSAL library, please illustrate if this can be a good option of using and how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement , As you have aware about for app registration we need to configure those in our application .

Here is an example of our `appsettigns.json` where we have provided Azure AD credential to our Asp.net application to authenticate with `MS IDENTITY` .

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb47",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx02",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

For complete setup for adding ***External identity to your application*** please refer this.

- ***Microsoft Documentation***:- [***How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using the Azure AD B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/how-to-secure-a-web-api-built-with-aspnet-core-using-the-azure-ad-b2c/)
- ***BLOG***:- [***Setup ASP.NET Core Web APIs To Use Azure AD Authentication***](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setup-asp-net-core-web-apis-to-use-azure-ad-authentication/)